# Facebook Plugin not showing on my desktop or mobile, but appears fine on another desktop

Tags: facebook, plugins

I've been using the Facebook Plugin for years, on dozens of websites, but all of a sudden, I can only see the page's facebook header, the actual feed appears only as a spinning icon.  This is on my desktop and mobile device, feed is at the bottom of the page.  https://saltydogfestival.com

screenshot_mobile

[image: 1]

However, my co-worker in the desk across from me tried it on his desktop and laptop and the feed loads just fine.

I'm not a page admin for this particular feed.

I have this plugin for other facebook pages, for which I AM an Admin, and those don't show up for me, either.  I've tried using Chrome and Edge.

I'm knocking my head against the wall with this.... or maybe it's something so simple that I'm not seeing it...  Suggestions??? Please save what's left of my sanity!

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue has affected many sites including mine. I used a third party plugin recently that's said to no affect page speed. It's called "Buttonizer - Smart Floating Action Button" you can add a FB messenger button also and add call to action and any they button as well. I have disabled the Facebook chat one for now. If you can update me if it's now work for you that would be great as I'm in the same boat. Email mtgusto@outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

*Edited - bug seems resolved*

This is what worked for me:

1. Go to [Facebook Developers - Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) and configure the 'widget' with desired params.
2. As you change the parameters the preview should update & show. If it doesn't, try signing out.
3. Click "Get Code" beneath the preview. I used the JavaScript SDK method.
4. Copy & paste the first piece of code after the < body > tag.
5. Copy & paste the second piece of code where the box should appear.

*Previous answer - leaving here for posterity / reference*

It seems to be an issue with Facebook that occurs **when the visitor is signed in to Facebook**. Try viewing the page in a private window or reload after you have signed out of Facebook to see if it loads when you are **not** signed in.

There's more information on a Facebook Developers bug report, which was just marked as closed 8/26, although it still appears to be happening: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/584988619248795/

This other community thread has a work-around - look for Dave's comment: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1018223139108570/

Comment: Ahh, that was GREAT info, thank you so much for posting that!  I just tried logging out of facebook first, refreshed my browser on the website, and sure enough, the feed showed up just fine.  I had to log back in to facebook to read the support threads, and then the webpage's feed reverted back to spinning. Then I read the other thread where it was suggested changing data-tabs="timeline" to data-show-posts="true" , so I changed that code, refreshed the browser and now it works when I'm still logged in.  Thank you, thank you, thank you :)